# Having trouble passing in file path for Cygwin

Tags: include, cygwin, include-path

Whenever I am trying to compile my project, it cannot find my header file `#include "sw_src/include/generic.h"`. I'm trying to use -I to pass in the file so Cygwin can find it, but it keeps saying there is no file. The file path is "C:/cygwin64/home/ProjectFile/sw_src/generic.h".This is for c++ btw.

I have cd'd to my Project file and I've tried gcc -I /sw_src generic.h and variations, which lead to a fatal error. I've also tried variations of "-I/C:/cygwin64/home/ProjectFile/sw_src/generic.h". Any help would be appreicated. I've seen some variations include the cpp file, but my project has none.

Comment: Use a prefix of `/cygdrive/c/` instead of `/c/` or `c:\\`. The `cygpath` utility will properly convert a windows path to a cygwin path.